Как сделать фоновое изображение в шапке сайта?
Только учусь программировать. Есть задание сделать блочный сайт. Первым блоком идет изображение в шапке сайта во всю ширину экрана. На изображение нужно будет добавить несколько слов. Изображение идет исключительно сверху, в шапке. Далее на белом фоне будет идти вся остальная информация  Кто знает, подскажите, как это сделать. Уже который час читаю интернет по данному вопросу, толку нет

Не верю. Что там вообще читать можно?

Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.



body {
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  height: 3em;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, silver, blue);
}
<header>Шапка</header>
Информация




@Qwerty Надо было ему  в body Byajhvfwb. засунуть - он же прям так и сдаст работу)

@ЕвгенийЛи, для начала ему надо уметь из сниппета делать html страницу, а потом препод может не засчитать градиент за картинку ;)

А как вы дальше собрались учится? По каждому заданию будете на SO спрашивать?


:root {
  --size-max-width: 1200px;
  --size-min-width: 375px;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.row {
  display: grid;
  place-content: start center;
}

.column {
  max-width: var(--size-max-width, 1200px);
  min-width: var(--size-min-width, 375px);
}

header {
  .row {
    background: url(https://picsum.photos/900/150) center/cover;
    height: 150px;
  }
}
<header>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">

    </div>
  </div>
</header>



